# Undefined reference to operator delete while compiling C++ with GCC

Tags: c++

When I compiled [project](https://github.com/Metaswitch/sipp/tree/899187a84c54d3e016c8df1636bed6a51057eef4) using `make`, I get these error:

```
$ gcc     \
 -o sipp   rijndael.o md5.o milenage.o auth.o xp_parser.o message.o scenario.o screen.o call.o comp.o sipp.o stat.o actions.o variables.o infile.o deadcall.o task.o socketowner.o listener.o opentask.o reporttask.o watchdog.o -ldl -lpthread -lncurses -lstdc++ -lm -L /usr/local/lib -L /usr/lib -L /usr/lib64

/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: message.o: in function `SendingMessage::SendingMessage(scenario*, char*, bool)':
/home/tiina/clearwater/sprout/modules/sipp/message.cpp:287: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: /home/tiina/clearwater/sprout/modules/sipp/message.cpp:299: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: message.o: in function `SendingMessage::parseAuthenticationKeyword(scenario*, MessageComponent*, char*)':
/home/tiina/clearwater/sprout/modules/sipp/message.cpp:539: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: /home/tiina/clearwater/sprout/modules/sipp/message.cpp:540: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: /home/tiina/clearwater/sprout/modules/sipp/message.cpp:548: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: message.o:/home/tiina/clearwater/sprout/modules/sipp/message.cpp:551: more undefined references to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)' follow
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: scenario.o: in function `createIntegerTable(char*, unsigned int**, int*)':
/home/tiina/clearwater/sprout/modules/sipp/scenario.cpp:1791: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: call.o: in function `call::add_call(int, bool, sockaddr_storage*)':
/home/tiina/clearwater/sprout/modules/sipp/call.cpp:394: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
/opt/rh/devtoolset-9/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/ld: call.o: in function `call::init(scenario*, sipp_socket*, sockaddr_storage*, char*, int, bool, bool, bool)':
/home/tiina/clearwater/sprout/modules/sipp/call.cpp:477: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned long)'
...
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [sipp] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/tiina/clearwater/sprout/modules/sipp'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

1. Why does it happen at link phase not compiling phase (from .c to .o)?
2. if some library is missing, how do I know which one?
3. It is said pkg-config can solve `undefined reference`, how do I know which lib should I use?

**EDIT**

When I changed gcc from version 9.3.1 to 4.8.5, the problem is gone. (Nothing else was changed).

Comment: You should not compile/link C++ code with gcc. Use g++.

Comment: (2) Google the function name, unless the function comes from your own code. (3) Pkg-config tells you compiler&linker flags to use a library, if you already know the library name.

Comment: Since you are using a C compiler, the standard library for C++ will not be linked which is why you get this problem. You could possibly solve it by adding the library manually (`-lstdc++`) but do as @Evg says to avoid the problem completely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined reference to new operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596867/undefined-reference-to-new-operator)

Comment: @Evg this is in project Makefile.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I manually change it to g++, result shows the same

Comment: @Evg, I manually used g++, the error remains

Comment: And how were all those object files compiled?

Comment: @Evg as in https://github.com/Metaswitch/sipp/blob/899187a84c54d3e016c8df1636bed6a51057eef4/Makefile. Same code, same compilation, but success in Ubuntu.

Comment: Builds out of the box on a `buildpack-deps` container with GCC 10.2.1. The final link command used g++ too. Did you run the `./autoreconf` and `./configure` commands as instructed in the README? Please clone the project from scratch and show us what commands you used.

Comment: @Botje Hi, The problem is gone when I changed GCC from version 9.3.1 to 4.8.5, and use 4.8.5 to compile .c to .o, no such problem. I don't know the reason.